# Changing state in React JS is not re-rendering parent

Tags: reactjs

My react app is a multi-page form. It goes to next page after clicking 'Next'. Currently I have some text that should have a css class when current page is page 1, and when user goes to next page, the css class should be removed for that text (the text is still displayed for all pages).

My actual code is much larger so I'm only posting all the important parts(I think) that are required for this questions.

```
import ChildComponent from '....';

class Parent extends React.Component {
    state = {
       page: 1, //default start page
       currentPageis1: true,
       currentPageis2: false,
       currentPageis3: false,
       
    }

    change = () => {
        const = {page, currentPageis1} = this.state;
        this.setState({
            page: page + 1 //to go to next page
        });
        this.setState({
            currentPageis1: !currentPageis1  
        });
    }

    showPage = () =>{
       const {page, currentPageis1} = this.state;

       if(page === 1)
       return (<ChildComponent  
               change={this.change} 
               currentPageis1={currentPageis1}
              />)

    }

    render(){
        return (
              <p className={this.currentPageis1 ? '': 'some-css-class'}>Some Text</p>
              <form>{this.showPage()}
    )
    }

}
```

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
     someFunction = e =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.change();
    }  

    render(){
        return (
           <Button onClick={this.someFunction}>Next</Button>
        )
    }

}
```

Currently, when I click Next button, the currentPageis1 updates to false. I checked it using Firefox React extension. But it does not re-render the page. Which means "Some Text" still has the CSS class.

My guess is className={this.currentPageis1 ? '': 'css-class'} in Parent class is only being run once (when the page is first loaded). Do I have to use lifecycle method? How do I make react re-render everytime currentPageis1 is changed?

Comment: I was expecting to see the Child component being returned inside the Parent component. Where is your Child component being rendered from currently?

Comment: Please check the edit.

Comment: Thanks. I think my solution below should still work. It looks like with the addition of the showPage handler after you click the button, the Child component should disappear since it doesn't meet your page condition.

Comment: That is true. There is additional code in showPage() that renders different pages based on page value. But showPage() only changes in <form> tag. The <p> tag above will be visible for all the pages. But I only want to add some stying to <p> tag for 1st page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are doing `<p className={this.currentPageis1 ? '': 'some-css-class'}>Some Text</p>`. In order to apply styles to only page 1, you should revert the values in your condition. When `currentPageis1` is false `''` value is picked up.
2. Also `this.currentPageis1` is wrong. You should use state i.e. `this.state.currentPageis1`

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/multi-step-form-setstate-issue-fix-626l8?file=/src/App.js)

**Like this**

```js
       <p className={this.state.currentPageis1 ? "some-css-class" : ""}>
          Some Text
        </p>
```

Comment: That's what I did first. But for some reason, what I have works. It's not working when I switch them. But in either case, the <p> tag has to re-render when currentPageis1 is updated.

Comment: updated the answer ...shd be all good, let me know.

Comment: It works, thanks! Can you tell me the difference between this.currentPageis1 and this.state.currentPageis1?

Comment: `this.currentPageis1` means that the `currentPageis1` is a property of your class component(Parent). For ex in your `Parent` component, `change` and `show` are properties and so is `state. So when you do `this.currentPageis1` the js compiler checks for a property called `currentPageis1` in Parent which doesn't exists and hence its value will be undefined. ..... On the other hand, when you do `this.state.currentPageis1`, you are referring to the state which has the key `currentPageis1` and obtains the correct value...

Answer (score 0):

- To get your style to render, you'll need to add the `props` keyword.
- Return Child component inside of Parent and pass the change method as
  a prop
- Also, updated your setState so you only call it once instead of twice
  in the change method

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    state = {
       page: 1, //default start page
       currentPageis1: true,
       currentPageis2: false,
       currentPageis3: false,
       
    }

    change = () => {
        const = {page, currentPageis1} = this.state;
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            page: page + 1,
            currentPageis1: !currentPageis1 
        });
    }

    render(){
        return (
    <div>
      <p className={this.props.currentPageis1 ? '': 'some-css-class'}>Some Text</p>
      <Child change={this.change} />
    </div>
     )
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried your solution. But it still has the css styling to <p>. currentPageis1 is updating when I click next but it's not removing the css class from "Some Text".